# Getting traceback error on Django installation?

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I am trying to get Django going with mySQL. I have started the app I can see all manage.py and other files. and in setting i changed:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'app',
        'USERNAME': 'root', 
        'PASSWORD': 'root', 
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
    }
}
```

I have installed mySQL separately, I have XAMPP I started it but when I run: 
python manage.py migrate

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I didnt have this problem before, I think there are some different versions of Django or maybe the MySQL giving me problems. 
I am using virtualenv and I have gone through many similar problems in Stackoverflow but no luck.

I have ran these commands:

```
pip install mysqlclient
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb (command not found) 
pip install mysql-python
```

still getting the same error.

Questions:

1. How can i remove all old versions of Django?
2. what is the solution for getting rid of this error?

Comment: You say you are using virtualenv, but your django app runs with libs from the system python3.6 installation.

Comment: So when I go to my project dir, i type source source py1/bin/activate before running migrate isnt that what i supposed to do to use the virtualenv?

Comment: Then your virtualenv is probably borked - after the activation of `py1`, what do you get when running `python -V`, `pip -V` and `pip list --format=freeze | grep -i "django=\|mysqlclient="`?

Comment: python manage.py migrate

Comment: Python 2.7.10, pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)      and i get nothing back from the last one

Comment: It looks like your virtualenv `py1` is corrupted, because `pip` should be pointing to `py1/lib/pythonN.M/site-packages/pip`. Try creating a new virtualenv, activate it and execute `which python` and `pip -V`. Both outputs should point somewhere inside your virtualenv and not the system python installation.

Comment: its pointing to system python, but both system and project are the same version. how can i point it back to project then?

Comment: can i just delete the entire pip python and django completely and start over? if so how?

Comment: You can delete virtualenvs by simply deleting the directories containing them. You can uninstall packages by running `pip uninstall -y pkgname`. Replace `pip` with `pip3` for `python3`. As for `python` installations themselves, you can't uninstall the system `python2` installation. Other than that, it depends on how you installed `python`: either you used Homebrew, then run `brew uninstall python python3 pip`, or you installed the official `.dmg` file, then drag the Python icon to trash from Launchpad.

Comment: Thank you. Ill give that a try